# List Listener not working !

Tags: android

My list is working but the code i am using for listening is not working at all,
what code i will have to use, if i want to go to another Activity (view) instead of toast

```
package com.NVT.android;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

public class Listview extends Activity {

private ListView list1;

private String array[] = { "Further Education", "Higher Education", "Employers & Training" };

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main1);

list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

// By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in

// list.

list1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));




// COPIED from android website



 ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });


}



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To switch to another activity you will have to do create an intent ,specify the target activity class and pass that intent to startActivity method.

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
  // create an intent 
     Intent intent = new Intent(yourCurrentActivity.this,targetActivity.class)
      startActivity(intent);   
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try printing to LogCat instead of Toast and make sure that code in side onClick listener is executing

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.i("DebugMessage", "clicked an item..");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getApplicationContext() in the Toast Message use YourActivityname.this..

Then give a static text instead of

```
((TextView) view).getText()
```

then if it works try with

`((TextView) view).getText()`....